# ¿Cómo se puede localizar con firebug el archivo HTML que contiene este label para traducirlo?

Tags: html, filezilla, firebug

Utilizando firebug, no soy capaz de saber dónde está el archivo que contiene este label que mediante filezilla quiero traducir al español manualmente. ¿Cómo deberí hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias! ;)

Comment: ¿Ese label se genera dinámicamente? no responde a tu pregunta, pero podrías hacer una búsqueda recursiva de "Select Date of Delivery" en el directorio del proyecto.

Comment: Buscando y buscando lo encontré, pero sin firebug...xD Si que aparece dinámicamente creo. Saludos! ; )